# Regarding regular expression in c#

Tags: c#, regex

What is the meaning of below reg exp,

```
?i:msie (?:7|8|9)\\.
```

which is used in the next statement:

```
Regex.IsMatch(context.Request.UserAgent, "(?i:msie (?:7|8|9)\\.)")
```

Comment: Seems like the expression tries to determine whether the end user is browsing with IE, versions 7, 8 or 9.

Comment: It's a regex to do what's know as *user agent sniffing*, which is a really bad way to do web design. For example, the site will likely do something stupid (like say "you need IE to use this site") when it encounters IE 10 or 11. Responsive web design, using feature detection, rather than agent detection, is a far better way to create web sites.

Answer (score 0):

This is the full explanation for your regex in c#:

```
(?i:msie (?:7|8|9)\\.)

Options: Case sensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn't match line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks; Parentheses capture

Match the regex below with these options «(?i:msie (?:7|8|9)\\.)»
   Case insensitive «i»
   Match the character string “msie ” literally (case insensitive) «msie »
   Match the regular expression below «(?:7|8|9)»
      Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «7»
         Match the character “7” literally «7»
      Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «8»
         Match the character “8” literally «8»
      Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «9»
         Match the character “9” literally «9»
  Match the backslash character «\\»
  Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.»
```

Comment: I'd suggest you have more provided a technical description of what the regex does, rather than an explanation.